# Ansible UNREACHABLE error after change user password on remote server

Tags: ssh, ansible, passwords, ansible-inventory

Summary: I've changed the password for the user "myuser" and "root" on a remote server manually. After that, I updated the password on Ansible inventory VARS but Ansible cannot connect anymore to this remote server.

If I roll back the password of both users to the previous one and update the Ansible hosts inventory file again. Ansible can connect again.

I did not find this problem searching on Google, so this is because I've created this question.

I've focused on logging the password used by Ansible enabling debug on the Ansible side, I've enabled the DEBUG for SSHD service on the remote server. But I can't figure out what's happening.

Another thing I've tried is to configure a RSA shared key. The key works properly but I want to understand why the normal user password stopped working for Ansible after the change in the remote server.

Of course, the credentials work properly if I connect through a normal SSH client.

Thanks in advance for the help.

--- UPDATE ---

I've tried the connection after several days and now it is working but using the new password.

Does anyone know if Ansible keeps some kind of "cache" that could explain the behavior I saw?